# Setting Batch size in configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.2.5. What is the exact use/meaning of the statement `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` in a hibernate configuration file?

From the documentation, I can see that we need to add this line in the configuration for batch processing otherwise, batch processing is disabled by default. Apart from that, what is the specific reason for assigning the above line to a number?

It is **not** like if I assign it to 30(suppose) then my batch will be able to insert/update/delete at max 30 rows, I tested this thing in my local. Then what is the use of the number we assign for this?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain: Say for example, you have one entity `Parent`, which has `one-to-many` relationship with another entity `Child` with initialization as `lazy`.

By defining `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30`, you mean that when you try getting the `Child` entities from `Parent` entity, **it will load them in batch size of 30** i.e. `30 Child` objects at a time, if its available 30 or more otherwise available number of objects.

e.g. If `Parent has  100 Child` objects lazily loaded, now you are iterating the `Child` objects, it will trigger 4 queries in the back-end to load Child object in chunk of `30, 30, 30 and 10`.

Hope this help!

Comment: ok, so is it like if no relations exists then this won't come into picture? And what do you mean by `lazy` initialization? Can you please explain these two?

Comment: @user182944: I was just gave an example. What it really means that hiberate will optimize the backend queries wherever it's possible but using batch processing as mentioned in my example where its triggering 4 queries instead of 100.

Comment: Are you sure this property is related to lazy loading and not updates, as written below by Anand? I think this one is relevant for lazy loading: hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size

Answer (score 2):

JDBC batch updates allow sending multiple update queries in a single batch to the database. It reduces the number of network calls. You can view it as uploading an uncompressed zip containing 20 files instead of sending 20 files individually.